# WSO2 API Cloud Timeout Error code 101504

Tags: wso2, wso2-cloud

I am getting the following respose while trying to assess my api endpoint:

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
   <am:code>101504</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type>
   <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
   <am:description>Send timeout</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

Kindly suggest what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, it is exactly what it says - looks like the backend service is only available intermittently so when it is not available - you get the timeout reported by the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a header to accept text/xml:
`'content-type': 'text/xml'`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the solution was to **Increase the Endpoint Timeout** from the **API Manager** as described here :

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/endpoints/resiliency/endpoint-timeouts/

1. Sign in to the API Publisher Portal.

   https://:9443/publisher

   Example: https://localhost:9443/publisher
2. Use your username and password to sign in.
3. Click on an API in the API Publisher Portal listing page.
4. Click Endpoints under API Configurations.
5. Click on the cogwheel, which is inline with the endpoint that you need to configure, and update the endpoint related configurations as required.
6. Go to Advanced Endpoint Configurations.
7. Increase Connection Timeout value

Comment: Thanks but What I did is just copied the steps from the link !